# Photodiode + OpAmp + Arduino: Further Amplification

Tags: arduino, operational-amplifier, photodiode

In order to measure the concentration of a methylene blue dye in water, I am using a 660nm high power LED and a photo diode with op amp setup as described [here](https://outsidescience.wordpress.com/2012/11/03/diy-science-measuring-light-with-a-photodiode-ii/). (schematic below):

[image]

I have tried two different photo diodes, [BPX 61](https://www.reichelt.de/Fotodioden-etc-/BPX-61/3/index.html?ACTION=3&LA=446&ARTICLE=5812&GROUPID=3045&artnr=BPX+61) and [BPW 34](https://www.reichelt.de/Fotodioden-etc-/BPW-34/3/index.html?ACTION=3&LA=446&ARTICLE=5804&GROUPID=3045&artnr=BPW+34) and with both the measured intensity from the smartphone flashlight as well as the 660nm LED were only ~0.01 V (as read by the Serial Monitor).

I then decreased the resistor used in the op amp scheme from 10 kOhm to 330 Ohm to 75 Ohm to 10 Ohm and the measured voltage increased up to ~0.60 V when I hold the LED Right on top of the photodiode.

This is a bit too small, especially as I want to put the diode further away and an absorber in between.

How I can increase the signal?

Comment: A proper schematic is necessary for you to get the help you need.  Assuming the resistor is the feedback resistor in a transimpedance amplifier, INCREASING it should give higher output.

Comment: ok thanks for the advice, I drew a schematic as you suggested.

Comment: You need to increase the resistor. If the photocurrent is 10uA and you want 3V out you would need R = 300K.

Comment: So you mean the Output voltage decreases from 10 Ohm to 10 Kiloohm and then increases again?
 I am familiar with the basic resistor calculation, especially the one for transimpedance amplifiers as in this link that luke gary posted in his answer: http://www.electronicdesign.com/analog/whats-all-transimpedance-amplifier-stuff-anyhow-part-1
My question is: why does my circuit behave oddly? I checked all the connections and polarities. Maybe my capacity is too large? Other sources mention several pF and I got 100 nF...

Comment: The light current for the BPX61 is only in the uA range. You need a MUCH bigger feedback resistor to get a higher output voltage ...probably in the 500k to 1M Ohm range. Read this: http://edge.rit.edu/edge/P09051/public/photodiodeamplifers.pdf   You are operating the diode in zero volt mode.

Comment: Thanks for that valuable source and the recommendation for higher resistor values! So I am operating in "photovoltaic" mode because the diode is connected to ground. I will buy a few resistors in the MOhm range and let you know if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

What you are building is a transimpedance amplifier. They get pretty tricky pretty quick if you are not careful. I would look in to the [OPT101](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/texas-instruments/OPT101P/296-23090-5-ND/251177) if you are able, it can make things pretty simple for low sensitivity projects. But to directly answer your question, you need more gain. A transimpedance amplifier works by converting a current (the signal that comes from the photodiode when a photon knocks some electrons loose) into a voltage through the feedback resistor. The output voltage at DC is really just V = I * R, where I is your photocurrent and R is Rf or your feedback resistor. Need more gain? make Rf bigger. There are quite a few problems with this in practice, but you should give it a shot first and see if you have any issues. Give [this a read](http://www.electronicdesign.com/analog/whats-all-transimpedance-amplifier-stuff-anyhow-part-1) if you can as well as [this book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/007024247X) if you are interested further.

Comment: The problem with that is that the measured voltage increases, when I decrease R1 in my schematic above. I went from 10 kOhm to 330 Ohm, to 75 Ohm, to 10 Ohm and the voltage at my analog pin increased from 0.01 V to 0.60 V with respective steps in between.

Comment: Have you tried rotating the Photodiode?

Comment: I just tried this after you asked and it doesn't make a difference which way I turn it.... :-O what does that mean? I thought that shouldn't be the case with a diode...

Comment: If you had the diode reversed it could give similar symptoms to what you are seeing. The positive voltage from the diode at the inverting input of the opamp would feed through the resistor to the output.  The lower the resistor the more feedthrough. Do you have  meter to measure the voltage at the input and output without using the Arduino?

Comment: Yes I have a multimeter but I wasn't too sure what to measure in this case. As far as I can see the voltage drop (in DC mode) across the diode is similar to the one at the output, meaning no (or at least nearly none) amplification takes place. Does that make sense?